# Large SharePoint lists - threshold limit

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, list-view-threshold, large-lists

How big of a problem is it having large lists with hundreds of thousands of items and views that grab 'em all out with no filtering what so ever?

The magic number of **5000 items per view** circulating all over the internet says that's a big no-no because of how SharePoint are querying the content database.

But we've tried raising the treshold limit at farm level to some really high values noticing... absolutely nothing. *It just works.*

What will/can happen in a worst case scenario? Some slow performance now and then or a total irreversible disaster?

SharePoint 2016 on prem with approximately 2000 frequent users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raising the LVT simply raises the lock level on the SQL side (this is a SQL Server limitation) from a row lock to a table lock. Depending on your use-case, performance of your SQL server, among other factors, this may or may not have significant impacts to the end user experience.

I generally recommend two things:

1. Isolate the Site Collection you need to raise the LVT on into it's own content database.
2. Disable the LVT on the specific List(s) only rather than Web Application-wide. This can be done via PowerShell `$list.EnableThrottling = $false`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it just works, are you testing with other users active at the same time? The issue there would be locking: the one large query might work fine while other users would have issues doing tasks while that query is running.

Multiple site collections can be stored in a single content database, so this locking issue would impact users interacting with those other site collections, not just users accessing the same list.

As it's pretty easy to configure indexed columns to support the views, the better path is to go ahead at set it up following best practices, as it's quite difficult to decrease the threshold after it's been raised for a period of time.